# Что значат в формуле Excel буквы RC?

Tags: excel

Что значат в формуле эти RC[]? Работал со старым екселем, где все было понятно и ячейки назывались буквами...

Comment: @harley, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что в старом, что в новом *Excel* возможно установить один из двух видов ссылок: *R1C1* или *A1*

В 2010:
*Файл-Параметры_Формулы, там Работа_с_формулами-Стиль_ссылок.*